# Finding the number of commands in command history

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I'm trying to find the number of commands I've executed. At first I thought the command below would work:

```
wc -l < $HISTFILE
```

But now I know that the number this command returns doesn't show the number of commands, because a command can be multi-line.

How can I find the number of commands in my command history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this command called `fc` that *processes the command history list.*

According to `man fc`,

> −l        (The  letter  ell.)  List the commands rather than
>   invoking an editor on them. The commands shall be
>                written in the sequence indicated by the first and last operands, as affected by −r, with each  command preceded by the command number.

we can use `fc -l` to list the commands previously entered. By default, this command prints the last 16 commands, in the following format:

```
 [number of command]  [command]
```

Now if we could get the last command and only print its number, that would be the number of commands in the history file. If we look at `man fc` again,

> −number   A negative decimal number representing the command that was
>   executed  number  of  commands
>                          previously. For example, −1 is the immediately previous command.

we can see that by specifying `-n`, we get the last n commands. So the command, `fc -l -1` would return the last command.

```
❯ fc -l -1
 3088  man fc
```

Now that we have that, we can simply print the first column of it, using `awk`:

```
❯ fc -l -1 | awk '{print $1}'
3089
```