# How much time has passed since first command in zsh

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, zsh, command-history

By executing this [command](https://superuser.com/a/1511806/735590),

```
❯ fc -l -1 | awk 'END{print $1}'
8845
```

I can see that I have 8845 commands in my history file. And I'm using [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), so my history file looks like this:

```
❯ head $HISTFILE                    
: 1575981231:0;exit 
: 1575981278:0;git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/powerlevel10k
: 1575981423:0;clear
: 1575981457:0;exit 
: 1575981463:0;sudo vim ~/.zshrc
: 1575981490:0;source $_
: 1575981540:0;exit 
: 1575981684:0;git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
: 1575981688:0;cd yay
: 1575981692:0;makepkg -si
```

So I can find my first command, like this:

```
❯ head -n 1 $HISTFILE
: 1575981231:0;exit
```

I understand that this time is Unix Time. I want to find out how much time has passed since I entered that command into my terminal, in a readable format like this: `2 days, 2 hours, 5 minutes, and 54 seconds`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to find the Unix time of the first command, then we can subtracts that time from the current time and convert it to a human-readable format.

```
❯ awk -F: 'NR==1{print $2}' ~/.zsh_history | tr -d ' ' 
1575981231
```

This command takes the first line of `~/.zsh_history` file and separates it by `:` and then prints its second field, which is the time we needed. We also trim extra spaces from the output of `awk` by piping it to `tr -d ' '`. So now we have the time of the first command. Now we need the current time, in Unix. That can be simply done  via this command:

```
❯ date +'%s'                               
1578207763
```

All that is left to do is to subtract the first time from the current time and convert it. Here's a bash script to do just that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# tsfc - time since first command
function display_time {
    local T="$1"
    local D="$((T/60/60/24))"
    local H="$((T/60/60%24))"
    local M="$((T/60%60))"
    local S="$((T%60))"

    (( $D > 0 )) && printf '%d days, ' $D
    (( $H > 0)) && printf '%d hours, ' $H
    (( $M > 0)) && printf '%d minutes, ' $M
    (( $D > 0 || $H > 0 || $M > 0)) && printf 'and '
    printf '%d seconds\n' $S
}

first="$(awk -F: 'NR==1{print $2}' ~/.zsh_history | tr -d ' ')"
now="$(date +'%s')"
difference=$((now - first))

display_time $difference
```

The function in this script is taken from [Stéphane Gimenez's answer on Unix.StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27014/223320), which displays the time we give it (in seconds) in a human-readable format.

Now you can write that script in a file, make it executable, copy it into `/usr/bin` and everytime you run it, you can see the time that has passed since the first command you executed in zsh.

[image: tsfc howto]